# Skype doesn't show users as online even after you log in on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, skype

Skype doesn't show users as online even after you log in. What should I do to fix this anomaly?

This happens on Windows Vista and with the latest version of Skype 5.3.0.120

Comment: You'll need to edit with more detail. At least your OS

Comment: Can someone re-open this question, the entire point of this site is to get some useful help. It's weird that moderators just 'Close' it, its not like am just randomly generating unwanted questions here. Quite irritating

Comment: It's helpful on both sides when your question does include pertinent information. Would you want people chiming in for Ubuntu fixes when you're on Vista?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the skype status isn't set to invisible.